# stickyTableHeader not working

Tags: jquery, sticky

I am trying to use stickyTableHeader to make my table header static while you scroll through a table and for some reason it is not working. I placed the code from [stickyTableHeaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/blob/master/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.js)

in to a js file, with `$(function(){
    $("table").stickyTableHeaders();
});` at the top of the file, but for some reason nothing happens to my table. I initialized it in my index.html with `<script src="pathtofile"></script>` and I know that is correct. Any help?

I am loading the data for my table dynamically with angular, so could that conflict with the jquery initialization for the table itself? Like, jquery doesn't know the table is there or something? (granted that in a separate html file that i use to call for the body it contains the tables structure, just that the data comes from angular calls.

*Note: It also resizes the width of the table headers and I do not know why, if someone to point me in the right direction for that*

Comment: I have also added `$("table").stickyTableHeaders();` to the jquery `$(document).ready(function() {` to see if it would call it while the stickytableheaders was in its own file, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the call to `$("table").stickyTableHeaders();` happens too soon, possibly before angular loads the content. Also on closer inspection of the stickyTableHeaders plugin it seems that click events aren't setup for delegation so they would only find html that was in the page when browser loaded it initially. You may have to customise it to get it working.

Comment: Thank you, it is just like you said. I did a quick test by adding `<script>$(document).ready(function() { $("table").stickyTableHeaders(); });</script>` to the top of the file that initializes the table. How would I around having to do this on every table page?

Comment: You could include that JavaScript code in the result returned by Angular but I'm guessing that's just JSON? I'd need to see the JS code that you've created for angular to help

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sticky-table-headers/0.1.24/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sticky-table-headers/0.1.24/js/jquery.stickytableheaders.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two script elements that I needed to make jmosbech's StickyTableHeaders work were:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/sticky-table-headers"></script>
```